# How to do repeated excution by makefile

Tags: makefile

I am using makefile to compile my program. After compiling, I want to do some test automatically and it will take several different files as the input. I am trying to do something like this:

```
test:
   gcc test.c -o test

run:
   ./test test1.nlb >> test_output.txt
   ./test test2.nlb >> test_output.txt
   ...
```

We may have more test files so I am thinking whether there is a way I can avoid typing all these names. I have tried something like:

```
FILE = $(wildcard *.nlb)
run:
   $(foreach file,$(FILE),./test $(file) >> test_output.txt)
```

But it didn't work.
Any ideas on how to write such a makefile? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the wildcard expanded to `foo.nlb bar.nlb baz.nlb`.  Then your recipe:

```
$(foreach file,$(FILE),./test $(file) >> test_output.txt)
```

would expand to:

```
./test foo.nlb >> test_output.txt ./test bar.nlb >> test_output.txt ./test baz.nlb >> test_output.txt
```

which as you can clearly see, is not a valid shell command.  Remember, make functions (with some special exceptions) are basically *text manipulation* functions.  They don't run commands, they just massage text.

You have two choices: you can either write your loop using shell syntax, not make syntax:

```
for file in $(FILE); do ./test $$file >> test_output.txt; done
```

Or you can add a semicolon into your make foreach loop, to separate the commands:

```
$(foreach file,$(FILE),./test $(file) >> test_output.txt ;)
                                                        ^^
```

which will expand to:

```
./test foo.nlb >> test_output.txt ; ./test bar.nlb >> test_output.txt ; ./test baz.nlb >> test_output.txt
```

which is a valid shell script.

Or better, use `&&` as a separator so if a test fails you'll notice it:

```
$(foreach file,$(FILE),./test $(file) >> test_output.txt &&)
```